# Storing household batteries

Tags: batteries, storage

I am looking to ways to best store my miscellaneous batteries, which consists mostly of AAA/AA batteries (both alkaline and NiMH), a few Lithium batteries, and assorted button cells. I think I have the environmental conditions sorted (cool, dry place, no direct sunlight, out of reach of children, etc), but I have a few specific questions:

1. Would storing cylindrical batteries so that their [end contacts touch](https://i.imgur.com/8oRUxoY) (see below) cause issues, or is this an OK way to store them? I know they won't complete a circuit (the container they are in is plastic), but I was wondering if I might nonetheless get corrosion (or other effects, like more rapid discharging)?

   [image: Storing batteries so that their ends touch]
2. I presume that storing cell batteries loosely ([like this](https://i.imgur.com/cb5acUF) - see below - note that there will be many more cells in that box over time) is a bad idea, as they could (if jumbled around) create a short circuit, correct? If so, is there a good way of storing them (except to keep them in the blister packs in which they originally came - which take up an inordinate amount of space!)?

   [image: storing cell batteries loosely]

Comment: If you have no choice but to put them in a jumble, add a piece of Scotch tape or electrical tape over one or both ends.  Peel it back off when you're ready to use the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that storing coin cell batteries in loose heaps is not a good idea.  Battery manufacturers warn against this.  I would store the batteries in trays or blister packs in which they came.  If a blister pack is too big to fit in my fridge, I can cut it into several smaller blister packs.

[image]  ([Source](http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/includes/pdf/Panasonic_Lithium_PrevQualityProblems.pdf).  Page 2.)

**P.S.**  The topic of EE.SE is about electronics *design*.  The questions about use of household and consumer electronics are off-topic on EE.SE, I'm afraid.  A question like this might work in the EE.SE chat, where the rules are somewhat more relaxed.

Comment: -1: Comments on questions go under the question, not into the answer.

Comment: I'd disagree - one can use the same batteries for various device prototypes when crafting those and then surely it would be one hundred percent on-topic just as how to store tin alloy.

Answer (score 2):

20mm batteries, ie 2032, 2016, 2025 fit nicely in nickel coin rolls. Nickels are about 21.5mm, dimes are about 16mm, pennies are 18mm, and quarters are 24mm. Blue painter's tape can be used to hold a stack together. You can tear it off as you remove batteries.

Answer (score 0):

I use ABS/polypropylene battery [storage cases](http://www.dx.com/p/abs-aaa-aa-batteries-storage-box-case-translucent-white-265664#.U3l1xnZEGsM) for AA & AAA rechargeable batteries:

[image]

They're about $12/10 pieces delivered.

Also very handy for carrying spare alkaline batteries when traveling, as it prevents them from shorting in your luggage, and it often seems I can get alkaline cells for about 1/5~1/10 the price at home (in bulk) compared to what I have to pay a few at a time when I don't know where to shop.

For ultra-light travel, I put four of them in a thick (4-6mil) plastic bag and tape it so they can't move.